# Calculations which won't recalculate

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I'm trying to make a simple calculator in Google Sheets with checkboxes for certain values. For simplicity I'll refer to these Checkboxes as A and B. What I would like to have is the user selects A, B, either, or both and have that output value. However, I want the user to be able to unselect these boxes, but the total from the first value is unaffected.

Right now I have A=5 and B=10. I can check both, and get 15 in a separate cell. I can then subtract that cell from the total. However, when I uncheck the boxes, the values, including the total reset. Is there a function I can use that will total only when commanded, and the result is independent of if the boxes are checked or not?

Answer (score 0):

### **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TrUmf8f4DU05RMcy1iz-3i3Mosu2vxM4O1ngp3HYE78/edit#gid=0)**

[image: 1]

- select or unselect checkboxes
- select desired mathematical symbol
- click on the equal symbol to get a result

---

**NOTE:** in order this to work as it should, you need to make a copy of this sheet and **allow the script**

---

- script is: 


  ```
  function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                              var source = ss.getRange('F1');
                              source.copyTo(ss.getRange('F2'), {contentsOnly: true}); }
  ```
- formula in **F1** is:


  ```
  =IF(C2="+", B2+D2,
   IF(C2="-", B2-D2,
   IF(C2="*", B2*D2,
   IF(C2="/", B2/D2, ))))
  ```
- values of checkboxes (**B2** and **D2**) are shadow-mirrored respectively in **B3** and **D3**
- cell **C2** has data validation - eg. choice to select one of math symbols **`" + ", " - ", " * " or  " / "`**
- range **A1:D1** is data validation range list for **C2** consisting of: **`" + ", " - ", " * " or " / "`**
- over the area of the cell **E2** there is transparent object (drawing / button) which is activated via single click upon which this object will execute the above script which will copy the value of cell **F1** and paste it in **F2** cell. transparent object is available by right clicking:

[image: 6]